# How do I delete those lines from a latex table?

Tags: tables

[image]

How do I delete those lines from a latex table?

```python
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ c |c|c|c| }
       & cell2 & cell3 & cell11\\ 
 \hline
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 & cell\\ 
 \hline
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 & cell\\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome :) // Please move the code from your comment to your post using the Edit button, and delete the comment afterwards. Thanks

Comment: Remove `|` and `\hline`.

Comment: Do you want to remove just the *segments* marked in the picture?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cell2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cell3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{cell11} \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    cell4 & cell5 & cell6 & cell \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    cell7 & cell8 & cell9 & cell \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Beside of remove `|`, you must take a look at the `booktabs` manual, that is designed to produce elegant tables, with a minimum of horizontal lines. Note that no blank lines also  add some space, so set `\arraystretch` is not a must:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}\toprule
         &  cell2 &  cell3 &  cell11 \\\cmidrule{2-4}
  cell4  & cell5  &  cell6 &  cell \\\addlinespace 
  cell7 & cell8  &  cell9 &  cell \\\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without | in {cccc}

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccc} 
{}&0&0&0 \\ 
\hline
0&0&0&0 \\ 
\hline
0&0&0&0 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

With | in {c|c|c|c|}

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|} 
{}&0&0&0 \\ 
\hline
0&0&0&0 \\ 
\hline
0&0&0&0 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

With | in {c|c|c|c|} but without hline

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|} 
{}&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (however, I prefer a tabular formatted with `booktabs` in the spirit of `booktabs`: see answer of Fran).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[first-col,first-row,hvlines]
       & cell2 & cell3 & cell11\\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 & cell\\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 & cell\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]